# Installing a Meteor Package from GitHub

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and custom packages. There is a meteor package on GitHub (https://github.com/MacNCheeze/meteor-ionic) which is a modified version of the meteoric:ionic package listed in the package repo.

I am wondering what command is required to add this package from GitHub into Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

This command should ne help: meteor add urigo:ionic and link to this package https://atmospherejs.com/urigo/ionic

Answer (score 0):

From the [markdown](https://github.com/MacNCheeze/meteor-ionic/blob/master/GUIDE.md) of `meteor-ionic`, it has the following dependencies

```
iron:router
fourseven:scss
meteoric:ionic-sass
meteoric:ionicons-sass
meteoric:ionic
```

They are published Meteor packages and the command to install one or multiple Meteor packages is

```
meteor add <package> [package...]
```

Have fun!

Comment: I am aware that it meteoric:ionic is a published package however the published version available in the repository is missing some components and the GitHub version I linked to has those missing components. In the end I made my own package using meteor create --package and using those files. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @iamchristos, Understood. It's good to know that you have made it.